# How to change the Domain Password for a user in LOCK scenario CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION condition in Custom Credential Provider in Windows 10

Tags: c++, credential-providers

I am writing a **C++ Custom Credential Provider for Windows 10** system.
I have successfully changed the domain user password in **CPUS_LOGON scenario**, When password expires  in

> ntsStatus == STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE

situation occurs in

> Credential :: ReportResult()

But in **LOCK scenario, i.e., CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION**, I am not able to Load "PasswordchangeUI" edit fields of

> OldPassword, NewPassword, and ConfirmPassword

on the Tile of Credential provider.

I'm using the following code to load these components.

```
HRESULT hr; ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents*
_pCredProvCredentialEvents;

  hr =
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldState((ICredentialProviderCredential*)this, SFI_LOGIN_NAME, CPFS_HIDDEN);  // successfully hides the field.
    hr = _pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldState((ICredentialProviderCredential*)this, SFI_PASSWORD, CPFS_HIDDEN);    // successfully hides the field.

   hr =
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldState((ICredentialProviderCredential*)this, SFI_OLDPASSWORD, CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_SELECTED_TILE);  // Fails to load the field.

   hr =
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldState((ICredentialProviderCredential*)this, SFI_NEWPASSWORD, CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_SELECTED_TILE);  // Fails to load the field.

   hr =
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldState((ICredentialProviderCredential*)this, SFI_CONFPASSWORD, CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_SELECTED_TILE); // Fails to load the field.
```

Where as in the above code I am successfully hide the SFI_LOGIN_NAME and SFI_PASSWORD  fields,
But I am not able to display the SFI_OLDPASSWORD, SFI_NEWPASSWORD and SFI_CONFPASSWORD.

I would be thankful to you, if any one could help in this issue.

Regards
Aslam

Comment: Don't forget to retarget submit button to one of new fields and return `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED` status to reactivate user input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence:

1. First try to add new fields.
2. Retarget submit button to one of new fields.
3. Hide old fields.
4. Return `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED` status to reactivate user input fields.

Alternative - try to use `SFI_PASSWORD` instead of `SFI_OLDPASSWORD`.

Comment: Following first 3 steps, I have displayed the fields in the Credential Provider tile. When entered the Old & New Password data and clicking Submit button, it has called GetSerialization() with "cpus == CPUS_PASSWORD_CHANGE" clause in it, has changed the Old Password with New Password in CPUS_LOGON condition. But I didn't understand the CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED status to reactivate user Input Fields. Please explain in detail steps for LOCK scenario, i.e., CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION event occurs, How to change password in this scenario.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. Does your provider called with all of those scenarios: `CPUS_LOGON`, `CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION` and `CPUS_PASSWORD_CHANGE`?

Comment: Yes, My Provider works with all the 3 specified scenarios CPUS_LOGON, CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION, and CPUS_PASSWORD_CHANGE. I am facing problem when i try to change password when i try to unlock (CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION) the system using my CP.