# Implementing 'User Must Change Password at Next Logon' in Custom Credential Provider V2

Tags: winapi, windows-authentication, change-password, credential-providers

I am developing a Custom Credential Provider V2, and already handling the case of CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD, CSampleProvider::Filter, displaying "Other user" tile and allowing to enter the system as another domain user. However, my Provider doesn't handle the case when a user is set to "user must change password on the next logon". I already viewed these posts:

[How to change the Domain Password for a user in LOCK scenario CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION condition in Custom Credential Provider in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300716/how-to-change-the-domain-password-for-a-user-in-lock-scenario-cpus-unlock-workst)

[Credential Provider V2 : Handle password expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75483625/credential-provider-v2-handle-password-expired)

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to implement this functionality in my Provider, and even though I could display the necessary fields for changing the password, the password itself is not being changed for a user, and the system crashes. I could provide necessary code snippets if needed and I would be glad if anyone could guide me or provide any information!

Comment: I suggest you could try to set `CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD` via SetUsageScenario. And you could refer to the thread:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/929b7283-562c-464f-ad4a-ba6699b52dbf/about-credential-providermodify-the-password-successlybut-the-password-is-null-when-the-password?forum=windowssdk

Comment: I am using exactly this in a scenario of CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD in GetSerialization() already. And I am handling the case, by setting a bool flag, when a user is set to change the password in ReportResult(), when it returns STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE. Then in that same function, I redraw necessary fields, and in the GetSerialization, I am handling this case by checking a bool flag, and in my debugger I can see that it seems to pass all of the procedures and seems to change the password. However, after that, my whole system and VM crashes. @Jeaninez-MSFT

Comment: the built-in password provider handle this. you at all need wrap this built-in provider and do self modifications, when/where need

Comment: if I am using CSampleProvider::Filter and excluding all providers except mine, how could I use only necessary features of the built-in provider? @RbMm

Comment: Are you dont know how wrap provider ?

Comment: I want to handle this case in my Custom Cred Provider, by not using any built-in providers. Do you have in mind what may case the crash of the system? Is it memory-related or system in itself cannot change the password when in a locked state?

Comment: So even if I wrap a built-in provider to handle necessary cases, by using CSampleProvider::Filter I will turn it off, right? However, this Filter is important in order to not show a user other tiles and for him to be able to use only my Custom Credential Provider. How would I solve this dilemma? If I choose to wrap the built-in provider, does it mean that I cannot exclude it in Filter? @RbMm

Comment: You write full noncens. Not exist any dilemma. Filter - disable, not wrap. Wrap when you create and call privider by self

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to handle this case in Credential Provider V2. You should wrap existing built-in provider for this use case, however keep in mind that you cannot exclude this provider in your CSampleProvider::Filter.

Comment: Of can exclude in filter

Comment: Any provider can be created as COM-object regardless of the filters and their settings